# Fixing Amazon EC2 Permissions

Tags: amazon-ec2, permissions

I accidentally change the permission to `chmod -R 777 /var` and now I cannot access the EC2 instance how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loosing access to an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance is a common encounter - how to approach this situation when you don't know the reason yet is addressed in Eric Hammond's excellent summary [Solving: "I can't connect to my server on Amazon EC2"](http://alestic.com/2009/08/ec2-connectivity). However, since you already now what caused this, you can apply his respective instructions [Fixing Files on the Root EBS Volume of an EC2 Instance](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root) right away, which boils down to:

[Note: this only applies to instances with [Amazon EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) based [Root Device Storage](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html), because only these can be stopped without loosing the root volume; put another way, take care not to terminate your instance instead ;)]

- start another EC2 instance
- stop the EC2 instance you can't access anymore
- detach the EBS volume from the stopped instance
- attach the EBS volume to the running instance
- SSH into the running instance
- mount the EBS volume in the running instance
- perform whatever fixes necessary, i.e. adjust the `/var` permissions in your case

Please see Eric's instructions for details on how to do this from the command line; obviously you can achieve all steps up to the SSH access via the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) as well, removing the need to install the [Amazon EC2 API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351), in case they aren't readily available already.

Good luck!