# Not able to login to EC2 instance after making changes to default ec2-user

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have been using key pairs to log in to my EC2 instance without any problems until I made some changes to the ec2-user.

I changed the group of the ec2-user (usermod) and changed the default file permission (umask), to give write permissions to the group.

I am not able to log in since this change. I get a "Server refused our key" error for the ec2-user.

The key has not been modified in any way. after changing the ec2-user permissions  we are not able to login that is sure .

Has anyone faced similar issues? Are we not expected to change properties/permissions of the default ec2-user? How does one recover from this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loosing access to an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance is a common encounter - how to approach this situation when you don't know the reason yet is addressed in Eric Hammond's excellent summary [Solving: "I can't connect to my server on Amazon EC2"](http://alestic.com/2009/08/ec2-connectivity).

However, since you already now that the problem is permission related, you can apply his respective instructions [Fixing Files on the Root EBS Volume of an EC2 Instance](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root) right away, see my answer to the related question [Fixing Amazon EC2 Permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/365587/fixing-amazon-ec2-permissions) for a short summary of this approach.

Good luck!